# Weird unexplainable "switch" between ids in Android XML

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml

I have a really weird problem.

This is my full XML code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">


    <TextView android:id="@+id/disp_nums" android:textSize="64sp"
        android:layout_width="200dp" android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center" android:gravity="center" android:text="1111" />

    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:orientation="horizontal">

        <EditText android:id="@+id/ent_nums" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:hint="Entered numbers" />

        <Button android:id="@+id/enter" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="0.37"
            android:text="Enter" />


    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:weightSum="90">


        <Button android:id="@+id/button7" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:textSize="40sp"
            android:text="7" android:layout_weight="30"/>
        <Button android:id="@+id/button8" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:textSize="40sp"
            android:text="8" android:layout_weight="30"/>
        <Button android:id="@+id/button9" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:textSize="40sp"
            android:text="9" android:layout_weight="30"/>

    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" android:weightSum="90">


        <Button android:id="@+id/button4" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:textSize="40sp"
            android:text="4" android:layout_weight="30"/>
        <Button android:id="@+id/button5" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:textSize="40sp"
            android:text="5" android:layout_weight="30"/>
        <Button android:id="@+id/button6" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:textSize="40sp"
            android:text="6" android:layout_weight="30"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout android:weightSum="90"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">



        <Button android:id="@+id/button1" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:textSize="40sp"
            android:text="1" android:layout_weight="30"/>
        <Button android:id="@+id/button2" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:textSize="40sp"
            android:text="2" android:layout_weight="30"/>
        <Button android:id="@+id/button3" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:textSize="40sp"
            android:text="3" android:layout_weight="30"/>

    </LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:weightSum="90">

        <Button android:id="@+id/button0" android:layout_width="90dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="60"
            android:text="0" android:textSize="30sp" />
    <Button android:id="@+id/delete" android:layout_width="40dp" 
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_weight="30"
         android:text="Del" android:textSize="24sp"/>

    </LinearLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

My "0" and "Del" buttons seem to be opposite in their actions. Meaning when I click "0" it actually deletes everything and when I click "Del" it types the "0" character. HOWEVER, when I simply switch (see second code) between their physical positions then they both do their right part.

```
<LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:weightSum="90">

    <Button android:id="@+id/delete" android:layout_width="40dp" 
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_weight="30"
         android:text="Del" android:textSize="24sp"/>

    <Button android:id="@+id/button0" android:layout_width="90dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="60"
            android:text="0" android:textSize="30sp" />


    </LinearLayout>
```

What could possibly be causing this?

Comment: Are you attaching an OnClickListener to the wrong id?

Comment: Afraid not. I tripple checked it.

Comment: but0 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button0);
  but0.setOnClickListener(this);
butdel = (Button) findViewById(R.id.delete);
  butdel.setOnClickListener(this);

Comment: What does the OnClick implementation look like?

Comment: A simple switch with cases. r.id.delete, r.id.button0 etc. But it cant be the code as just switching the order of the buttons appearance makes it all work right. Can it?

Comment: That is a good point, I misread the code. What happens if you use inline click listeners? For example   butdel.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() { @Override
   public void onClick(View v) { theClass.this.DoDelete(); 
}});

Comment: You will not believe this...SAME THING even after inline listeners :-(
I cancelled the switch and wrote the inliners manually. No good.

Comment: In 8 hours I'll be able to post this as an answer:

Well, I appear to have fixed the problem.
Android\Eclipse seems to have an issue with the word "delete" as an ID.
I simply changed it to "buttondel" and everything was restored.

As I said...WEIRD.

Comment: Indeed very weird. I'm glad that you figured it out. I'll keep that in mind for my own development.